# Iterate through part of string in python to remove it from textfile

Tags: python, string, loops, text-files

I have a textfile which numbers certain situations like this:

*********** # 1 **************

Textline I want to keep

Another line I want to keep

I tried iterating through it because it goes all the way to 570 situations.

I tried it like this and it will remove the first `*********** # 1 **************`

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Serto\PycharmProjects\MVCOPY\jeroen.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open(r"C:\Users\Serto\PycharmProjects\MVCOPY\jeroen.txt", "w") as f:
    #getal = 1
    for line in lines:
        getal = 1
        if line.strip("\n") != "*********** # "+str(getal)+" **************":
            print(line)
            f.write(line)
            getal += 1
```

But somehow I can't get getal to add one everytime. It will only delete the first one.

I am expecting to remove all the `"*********** # "+str(getal)+" **************"` but it only removes the first

Comment: can you add expected output

Answer (score 0):

Either use regex with a wildcard character for the number in between asterisks or increment getal in the else block. I suggest the second solution.

Edit:

```
getal = 1
for line in lines:
    if line.strip("\n") == "*********** # "+str(getal)+" **************":
        getal += 1
    else:
        print(line)
        f.write(line)
```

Your code should look similar to this.

Comment: This didn't do anything for me.